# Map operation to update data | Hazelcast IMap returns clone object

Tags: java, hash-map

I have a nested hazelcast distributed map:

```
Map<CountryId, Map<CityCode, Map<data_key,data_value>>>
```

where "data_key" is "population", "literacy_rate" and "gender_ratio".
Below is the class where I have implemented a method which adds new city data to a specified country.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.Min;
import net.sf.oval.constraint.NotNull;
import net.sf.oval.guard.Guarded;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;


/**
 * Provides CacheOperation implementation for CountryRepository. 
 *
 * @author Praveen.Puskar
 * Created: 12:27:37 PM, Apr 13, 2015
 */
@Guarded
public class CountryCacheOperation extends
        AbstractCacheOperation<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> {

    /**
     * Instantiates a CountryCacheOperation.
     *
     * @param cache the cache
     */
    public CountryCacheOperation(
            @NotNull IMap<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> cache) {
        super(cache);
    }

    /**
     * Add city to country.
     * 
     * @param countryID id of the country to which city will be added.
     * @param cityCode cityCode to which data is required to be associated.
     * @param data a map containing city data :
     *          <ul>
     *              <li>litracy_rate</li>
     *              <li>population</li>
     *              <li>gender_ratio</li>
     *          </ul>
     */
    public void addCityToCountry(@Min(1) int countryID,@NotNull String cityCode,@NotNull Map<String, Object> data) {
        cache.lock(countryID);
        try {
            cache.putIfAbsent(countryID, new HashMap<>());
            Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = cache.get(countryID);//cache.get(..) returns clone of data.
            map.put(cityCode, data);
            cache.put(countryID, map);
        }
        finally {
            cache.unlock(countryID);
        }
    }

}
```

Kindly review the logic to add new city to any country. Point to consider:

- `cache.get(KEY)` returns clone of the object so it is required to put the updated data again to cache.